# Can we hide the woocommerce product with price 0 or no price?

Tags: woocommerce, hide, product, zero

Everyone:
I wanted to ask, if there is a way (custom coding or plugin) to hide the product which have no price or the price is 0?

Comment: You will need to post more information for your problem. Best way is to post most important part of source code. If you wanna fast answer.

Comment: what do you mean by hide?

Comment: @NikolaLukic, sure.

Comment: @Reigel I meant not be visible on the shop page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Put this code in functions.php file

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'themelocation_product_query' );
function themelocation_product_query( $q ){
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => '_price',
                'value'     => 0,
                'compare'   => '>'
            );
$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, it helped for my case.